# Http error uploading wordpress file size over 10mb

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I am getting an error while uploading a file over 11MB. Tried both single and modern uploader but showing http error. 
Single uploader showing 413 error.

My wordpress settings are:

max_execution_time  300
max_file_uploads    20
max_input_time  60
max_input_vars  1000
memory_limit    900M
post_max_size   500M
upload_max_filesize 500M

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess there was a settings "LimitRequestBody 10240000". I modified it to "LimitRequestBody 51200000" and it solved.

Probably anyone could get help with this.

Thanks